# Divide changefeed query results between many sessions

Tags: web-services, jobs, rethinkdb

So I have a service that has to make some long computation every time user makes an REST API call. Right now a http handler pushes some data to a table in RethinkDB and a background job uses changefeed to fetch the data and make computations.

Data: `{ id: RethinkDB's UUID, payload: ... }`

Now I want to:

- **Make the background process run in parallel on several machines**
- **Use fancy ReQL to dispatch different tasks to different machines**
- Avoid duplicating computations

---

One idea I have is to:

1. Give each process a separate *process_id* (1,2,3..)
2. Map Data's *ID* to a number (*num_id*)
3. Use Changefeed in each process and wait for data where num_id % max_process_id is process_id

**Does anybody have a better idea?**

**Is there any canonical way to automatically dispatch changefeed query into several machines?**

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea you described sounds like a good way to do it.  Changefeeds don't have any built-in way to dispatch to multiple workers like that.